# New Facebook-access-token generated if it expires?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-access-token

I am using the below API to list out my Facebook friends.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=???

I wish to know what would happen when the access token expires.

1) If I have logged out of Facebook, and try to re-login my app via Facebook-connect, new access token is generated in my app.

2) But if I am already a logged-in Facebook user, and I am using iOS5.0 or above, and try to login my app via Facebook-connect, **will it show expiration error? Or is new access token generated?**

Comment: Can't you check this on your own?

Answer (score 1):

Default access tokens expire after 2 hours, if you login again a new access token is generated.

Here is more: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

Comment: Even-though it is said that the Device token created would expire in 2 hours, it is proved wrong in my case. I have created 1 yesterday and its expiration date is 15th Dec.

Comment: there are also long living tokens, accessible for 60 days. but normally the token is not usable 2 hours later. the date does not say very much about the usage though...